# How to get a reference to the IMG element from MAP's eventhandler function?

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

Say we have an `IMG` (`id`less) element which has an `usemap="#hotmap"` attribute. Then we have this `<MAP name="hotmap">` element (in the `BODY`) containing an enormous amount of `AREA`s (say >1000). It's obvious, that we'd like to delegate the eventhandling of `AREA`s to the `MAP` element instead of creating hundreds of eventlisteners.

Now in the eventhandler function (for `MAP`) we'd like to get a reference to the `IMG` which uses the `MAP` which fired the event. However, `MAP` is in the `BODY` and `IMG` element can't have HTML, thus `MAP` can't be among its children. So the question is, how can we catch the `IMG` in this eventhandler?

A trivial example:

```
<img src="some_image.png" usemap="#hotmap" />
                ...
<map id="map" name="hotmap">
    <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,50" />
                ...
</map>

map.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var area = e.target,
        image = ?; // How to refer the img
        ...
}, false);
```

---

**Side notes**

I'm working on a HTA project where I need an object which dynamically creates and assigns hotmaps for images which have certain custom attributes. This object gets its data for `AREA`s from external file, and everything is working fine, except this one little detail. For now, I'm adding a custom property containing a reference to the "user" `IMG`, to each `AREA`. Though this would be unnecessary, if it could be done only once in the eventhandler.

**EDIT**

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2ZmT/3/), (not HTA included, works in any(?) modern browser)

---

**EDIT II**

I just realized, that I can't reuse the `MAP`, since it can be also resized according to the `IMG`. So I've put the reference to the `IMG` to the `MAP` instead of its `AREA`s.

Though this solved my problem, I'd still like to know, how to get the `IMG` in the eventhandler, just in general. The suggested `querySelector()` solution seems not work (tumbled with it earlier, now it returns `undefined`)

Comment: can you please post a complete markup containg the image and the starting map-tag.

Comment: @Dr.Molle It's far too large to post here, but I'm working on a jsFiddle just now. It'll take some time, since I've to convert results from HTA file actions to arrays to get it work in regular HTML page.

Comment: After you edit I don't need it anymore, sorry. The markup isn't relevant when you use the map with multiple images.

Comment: My solution for similar problem:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571861/get-img-tag-id-when-click-on-map-area-of-this-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At first:**
Be careful with the methods you use there, HTA by default runs with IE7(standards-mode content) or IE5(quirks-mode content), so you can't rely on features that are available in your IE. 
I would suggest to use only methods that are available in IE5, e.g. use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`.

Following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Compatibility)  you should be able to define the compatibility, but for me it doesn't work.

**Related to the question:**

Instead of observing the click-event of the map, observe the click on the img.
When you observe the click on the map, and the map is used by multiple images, there is no way to find a relation between the map and the image.

Comment: At first: No worries, this is a stand-alone desktop application, which requires IE9 installed. Everything is tested and works, when IE9 is available. Related to the question: I tried this, but then I couldn't get the `AREA` which actually was clicked. This is weird, since if there were for example `DIV`s to click, they could be traced in eventhandler. Anyway, thank you for your replies. If nobody won't prove this "negative" answer incorrect, I'll accept it during a couple of days.

Comment: When IE9 is available and everything works fine, why does your HTA throw an error when you use querySelectorAll? I have also IE9 installed, and querySelectorAll and addEventListener are not available inside HTA.

Comment: Hmm... Hard to say without seeing the code, but a civilized quess would be, that you have either `<style>` tags or `<link rel="styleSheet"...>` before the `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>` tag. Notice, that there's an error in the example of that page in MSDN, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is also required, though it's not included in the example code.

Comment: I was just about to add `<script>`s to my comment, but it was too late. Anyway, any code which could possibly affect to the document's compatible mode, should be placed after `x-ua compatible`. Safest form I've found is: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>title</title><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>`. After this you can include what ever you want.

Comment: Actually you were right when you suggested to observe image clicks instead. Only I had to do was to append the map to the image itself, not to the `body`.