# Get img tag id when click on map area of this image

Tags: javascript, html, image, shapes, area

I have some images-figures with map-area like this

[image: image area]

and i need get image id when click inside area zone
can i made it without custom area functional realisation with js?

**UPD** [sandbox](http://goo.gl/BRkBM)

**UPD2** found second, other problem.
first area zone (red), which covered by second image not clickable and z-index for area not working.

[image: image problem]

**FINAL UPD** 
I wrote small custom function for mapping some objects.
Maybe it will help someone:
[jsFiddle](http://goo.gl/UE97C)

Comment: I didn't try something successful.
e.target return area id, elementFromPoint isn't good in this situation because one area is laying over another image

Comment: to clarify; you want to get the image id when you click on it?

Comment: i want get image id when click on it inside it's map area

Comment: Is the "map area" based on the image's border or is it an area you specifically create? I am guessing in those gray areas, if you click there it would not select?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421518/how-to-get-a-reference-to-the-img-element-from-maps-eventhandler-function . I just asked this few days ago ;).

Comment: It would help if you posted some HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

JS Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/g5Dy3/44/

**HTML**

```
<img id="dotted" src="image1.jpg" usemap="#ballmap" alt="sample" />
<img id="solid" src="image2" usemap="#ballmap2" alt="sample" />

<map name="ballmap">
    <area shape="circle" coords="210,120,90" href="#" alt="dotted ball" title="dotted ball" onclick="clickedMe(this);">
</map>
<map name="ballmap2">
    <area shape="circle" coords="126,90,70" href="#" alt="solid ball" title="solid ball" onclick="clickedMe(this);">
</map>
```

**JS**

```
function clickedMe(item) {
    var mapName;
    mapName = $(item).parent().attr('name');
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('usemap') == '#'+mapName){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));            
        }       
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, it's solution, but for every image you need create maps.. I thought about this in structure <li><img><area></li> and take previous element of clicked area, but all areas are siblings and there is lots of images. I dont want making so much maps. it will be better if i make custom matrix with js for detect zones.

Answer (score 1):

Like so assuming you can use jQuery:

```
<img id="planetsimg" src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" onclick="clicked(this)" alt="Sun" image-id="planetsimg">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" onclick="clicked(this)" alt="Mercury" image-id="planetsimg">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" onclick="clicked(this)" alt="Venus" image-id="planetsimg">
</map>

<script>
function clicked(map) {
    var image = $('#' + $(map).attr('image-id'));
    alert('img ' + image + ' clicked map ' + $(map).attr('href'));

    return false; // Prevents href from opening normally. Return true if you want the link to open
</script>
```

Comment: please do not use click handlers like that (see my solution)

Answer (score 0):

just add the clickhandlers to the areas (images) of your map, not to the map itself

if you are using jQuery, you can do it like that:

```
$('map').find('area').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click',... 
});
```

Comment: i dont want id of area. how it helps get image object?